# Why does a .csv file lose kilobytes when it is saved as the same file, just under a different name?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I had a .csv file called "removed.csv" whose size was 3,959kb, but when I saved it under a different name, "uncleaned_df.csv", its size suddenly became 3,784kb. I've verified that I haven't changed anything within the csv file, and I've done it with different names as well. Is there any reason for there to be a drop in the file size?

Comment: If there were blank lines in the original file, or trailing spaces on the lines, or spaces embedded in the lines, then saving the file again as a .CSV would eliminate all of that white space.  Have a look at both files and compare them for white space.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you so much - is there any chance that the removal of blank spaces would cause any data analysis problems? I'm currently using the csv files for some minor analysis.

Comment: "White space" is thrown away during the process of reading in a .CSV file.  They are there only so that humans can read the file more easily.  It is also possible that if the original file had floating point numbers with trailing zeros (e.g. 12.473000), those trailing zeros were removed when it was saved again.

Comment: Use a compare program (e.g. Winerge there are many others) that will tell you exactly what has changed

Comment: @GoGoCrash Please don't post answers, even partial ones, in the comments. Post an answer instead.

Comment: @Twisty:  If that is the site attitude, then I'm done contributing here.

Comment: @GoGoCrash If you provide a poster with a useful answer, not only do you deserve credit for that, you deserve credit for future visitors who also find it helpful. This happens through voting, but only answers can receive votes. This isn't an attitude, but rather how the site is designed to recognize your contribution. Posting answers in the comments undermines this site's purpose to collect high - quality answers...a process which requires answers to be posted as answers. I hope that explains my comment.